# Should you first push and then merge to master?

Tags: git

Let's say I have a working branch A.

I do changes to A and add a commit message to it. Then I push the branch to the remote repository and then merge it into master?

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty subjective question. You can do it like that. I usually have an intermediate branch for testing before I merge anything to master.

Comment: yes, that is pretty much it. There are 2 ways you can merge though which is probably worth mentioning. You can merge where a new commit will be created with the changes or you can go the rebase way, which basically puts the changes from your branch on top of a target branch (master in your case) without creating a merge commit. Also, I think this would help you https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate your new changes (on branch A) to your remote main branch named master, yes you'll have to push something at some point.

If you're using some git hosting service like github, bitbucket, gitlab or the like :

- push your branch to remote
- go to the webpage for your remote repo
- create a Pull Request from your branch A to master

Alternatively, if the remote is hosted somewhere without a web interface, or if you're alone on your repo or don't have a protected master branch, another way to proceed is to :

- get on your local master branch
- merge branch A into master
- push master to remote

Answer (score 1):

If the commit you made will eventually work its way into master, it doesn't really matter.

A branch is in git is a reference to a commit, nothing more.  By pushing your branch working branch before merging to master, all you are doing is updating the remote's knowledge of which commit the working branch should be pointing to. If you merge to master and then push only master, the remote's copy of the working branch won't be updated. If it is a temporary branch, maybe you don't care because you're going to delete the branch anyway. If it is a longer running branch, you might want to push to both branches so the remote's copy is up to date.

Really it's a question of what you want your branches to reference when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with the below steps.

1. `Commit` your current changes to the `A` branch.
2. `Push` your changes to the GitHub.
3. `Switch` branch from `A` to the `master` branch in your local computer.
4. Then merge the `master` branch from branch `A`.
5. Finally `push` your merge into the GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The order is `commit` → `push`to your branch → Make a `merge request` → Accept the `merge request`

Explanations: you can also just **commit** and **push** to your branch but changes and commit will so stay on your remote branch.

Once you are ready to merge your branch to the master, you have to make a **merge request** to it.

More docs: [How to create a merge request ?](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/add-merge-request.html)

Answer (score 0):

"Right" is pretty hard to nail down. There is no one size fits all workflow, and your workflow could change based on the requirements of the project and the preferences of the people working on the project.

I like to:

1. Commit local changes to local branch
2. Pull from master branch
3. Resolve any conflicts, if any
4. Verify changes
5. Push to remote branch
6. Pull request

Check out this [link](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for one man's (very) thorough take on Git best practices.